# Making a live clock in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, setinterval, clock

The clock kinda works. But instead of replacing the current time of day it prints a new time of day every second. I understand why it does that but I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate if you could give me some tips without saying the answer straight out. Here is my code:

```
function time(){
    var d = new Date();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var h = d.getHours();
    document.write(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
}

setInterval(time,1000);
```

Comment: Well, `document.write` does just add stuff to the document, so you will get multiple lines of output. You want to _replace_ the output instead of keep adding to it.

Comment: For anyone coming across this in the future, if you want your updates to sync with the system clock, I made a tiny package: https://github.com/pejalo/top-of-second-ticker

Answer (score 33):

Add a span element and update its text content.

```js
var span = document.getElementById('span');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = 
    ("0" + h).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).substr(-2);
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

**Answer updated [2022]** https://stackoverflow.com/a/67149791/7942242

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even think about that. Should have understood that. Anyways thank you!

Comment: @williamganrot :  glad to help you

Answer (score 21):

You can also use toLocaleTimeString() on Date() to just get your display date instead of creating through so many variables.

```js
window.onload = displayClock();
function displayClock(){
  var display = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  document.body.innerHTML = display;
  setTimeout(displayClock, 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` within the setInterval function.

```js
setInterval(() => console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()),1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my answer, hope it may help.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    let a;
    let time;
    setInterval(() => {
      a = new Date();
      time = a.getHours() + ':' + a.getMinutes() + ':' + a.getSeconds();
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
    }, 1000);
  </script>
  <span id="time"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

I have used the `setInterval` arrow function and declared the variables `a`, `time` outside so as to avoid repeated allocation, where the span id(time) runs for a specified interval(here it is 1000) and `document.getElementById("time")` call gets you the element by the specified ID and also it's setting the `innerHTML` of that element to the value of `time`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain in your answer what your code solves, instead of just posting some code...

Comment: I have updated my answer with explanation, @Klaassiek ,thank you, it was my first time answering, would not repeat again.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow this link https://codepen.io/uniqname/pen/eIApt you will get your desire clock or try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question states *if you could give me some tips without saying the answer straight out*

Answer (score 2):

Code will display clock in digital format

```js
function myClock() {         
  setTimeout(function() {   
    const d = new Date();
    const n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n; 
    myClock();             
  }, 1000)
}
myClock();
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <div id="demo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Above code will display clock in digital format

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be nicely done using ES6.

```js
const clock12 = document.getElementById('clock12')
const clock24 = document.getElementById('clock24')

// Concatenate a zero to the left of every single digit time frame
function concatZero(timeFrame) {
  return timeFrame < 10 ? '0'.concat(timeFrame) : timeFrame
}

function realTime() {
  let date = new Date()
  let sec = date.getSeconds()
  let mon = date.getMinutes()
  let hr = date.getHours()
  // 12 hour time
  // If the hour equals 0 or 12, the remainder equals 0, so output 12 instead. (0 || 12 = 12)
  clock12.textContent = `${concatZero((hr % 12) || 12)} : ${concatZero(mon)} : ${concatZero(sec)} ${hr >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`
  // 24 hour time
  clock24.textContent = `${concatZero(hr)} : ${concatZero(mon)} : ${concatZero(sec)}`
}

setInterval(realTime, 1000)
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: consolas;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="clock12"></p>
  <p id="clock24"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the above code get the am/pm wrong between midnight and 1am?  It should display 12:xx AM, but will show 12:xx PM.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the root of your problem

> But instead of replacing **the current** time of day it prints **a new** time of day every second.

then you can't make the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) responsive, because

> JavaScript Date objects represent **a single moment** in time in a platform-independent format.

If you don't wish to create a new object every second, you can register a dedicated [Web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) that calls [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) every second, but this is more demanding on system resources than simply creating the Date object, which just copies the actual **system** clock (thus not creating a separate process for measuring the time). **tl;dr:** just create a new Date object every second as you do.

The root of your `document.write()` issue stems from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> Because document.write() writes to the document stream, calling document.write() on a closed (loaded) document **[in setInterval in your case]** automatically calls document.open(), which will **clear the document**.

To update part of your page, you usually set [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of some element as @Pranav suggests.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function clock() {
      var clockDiv = document.querySelector("#clock");
      return setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date();
        let tick = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        clockDiv.textContent = tick;
      }, 1000);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="clock()">
  <div id="clock"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that the code isn't loaded exactly at the turn of a second plus there's a small natural drift. So if you care about the exact seconds you also need to keep it at sync.

Here's an example **continuing on yusrasyed's answer** from above:

```
window.onload = displayClock();
function displayClock(){

  const d = new Date();
  var sync = d.getMilliseconds();
  var syncedTimeout = 1000 - sync;

  var display = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.body.innerHTML = display;

  setTimeout(displayClock, syncedTimeout); 
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer on this page that accounts for drift. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function () {
  const time = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
  span.textContent = time
}, 1000)
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A working demo, follow the link

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

**Updated**
you are using document.write which appends the current time each time (and that's what your problem was if I am not wrong). 
So for replacing previous time with new time -
1. you have to open document with replace mode (as shown in code below)
2. you write the current time
3. then you close the document.

```
function time(){
    var d = new Date();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var h = d.getHours();
    document.open("text/html", "replace");
    document.write(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
    document.close();
}

setInterval(time,1000);
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I've updated my answer, hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

anyone wanting to know how to code a digital clock with alarm? Here is my codepen http://codepen.io/abhilashn/pen/ZLgXbW

```js
function AmazeTime(almbtnobj) {
 this.date,this.day,this.dt,this.month, this.year,this.hour,this.minute,this.second = null;
 this.almHour, this.almMinute, almMeridiem = null;
 this.meridiem = "AM";
 this.almBtn = almbtnobj;
 this.almBtn = this.setAlarm;
}

AmazeTime.prototype.initializeTime = function() {
 this.dt = new Date();
 this.day = this.getDayInWords(this.dt.getDay());
 this.date = this.dt.getDate();
 this.month = this.getMonthInShort(this.dt.getMonth());
 this.year = this.dt.getFullYear();
 this.hour = this.setHour(this.dt.getHours());
 this.minute = this.doubleDigit(this.dt.getMinutes());
 this.second = this.doubleDigit(this.dt.getSeconds());
 this.meridiem = this.setMeridiem(this.dt.getHours());
}

AmazeTime.prototype.setHour = function(hr) { 
 if(hr > 12) {
  hr = hr - 12;
 }
 if(hr === 0) {
  hr = 12;
 }
 return this.doubleDigit(hr);
}

AmazeTime.prototype.doubleDigit = function(val) {
 if(val < 10) {
  val = "0" + val;
 }
 return val;
}
AmazeTime.prototype.setMeridiem = function(hr) {
 if(hr > 12) {
  hr = hr - 12;
  return "PM";
 } else {
  return "AM";
 }
}

AmazeTime.prototype.getMonthInShort = function(value) {
 switch(value) {
  case 0:
   return "Jan";
   break;
  case 1:
   return "Feb";
   break;
  case 2:
   return "Mar";
   break;
  case 3:
   return "Apr";
   break;
  case 4:
   return "May";
   break;
  case 5:
   return "Jun";
   break;
  case 6:
   return "Jul";
   break;
  case 7:
   return "Aug";
   break;
  case 8:
   return "Sep";
   break;
  case 9:
   return "Oct";
   break;
  case 10:
   return "Nov";
   break;
  case 11:
   return "Dec";
   break;  }
}

AmazeTime.prototype.getDayInWords = function(value) {
 switch(value) {
   case 0:
    return "Sunday";
    break;
   case 1:
    return "Monday";
    break;
   case 2:
    return "Tuesday";
    break;
   case 3:
    return "Wednesday";
    break;
   case 4:
    return "Thursday";
    break;
   case 5:
    return "Friday";
    break;
   case 6:
    return "Saturday";
    break;
 }   
}

AmazeTime.prototype.setClock = function() {
 var clockDiv = document.getElementById("clock");
 var dayDiv = document.getElementById("day");
 var dateDiv = document.getElementById("date");
 var self = this;
 dayDiv.innerText = this.day;
 dateDiv.innerText = this.date + " " + this.month + " " + this.year;
 clockDiv.innerHTML = "<span id='currentHr'>" + this.hour + "</span>:<span id='currentMin'>" + this.minute + "</span>:" + this.second + " <span id='meridiem'>" + this.meridiem + "</span>";
}

AmazeTime.prototype.setAlarm = function() {
 this.almHour = this.doubleDigit(document.getElementById('almHour').value);
 this.almMinute = this.doubleDigit(document.getElementById('almMin').value);
 if(document.getElementById("am").checked == true) {
  this.almMeridiem = "AM";
 } else  {
  this.almMeridiem = "PM";
 }
}
AmazeTime.prototype.checkAlarm = function() {
 var audio = new Audio('http://abhilash.site44.com/images/codepen/audio/audio.mp3');
 if(this.hour == this.almHour && this.minute == this.almMinute && this.almMeridiem == this.meridiem) {
  audio.play();
  if(this.minute > this.almMinute) {
   audio.pause();
  }
 } 
}

var mytime = null;
mytime = new AmazeTime(document.getElementById("savebtn"));
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
 function runTime() {
 mytime.initializeTime();
 mytime.setClock();
 mytime.checkAlarm();
 }
setInterval(runTime, 1000); 
} , false); 

function saveAlarm() {  
 mytime.setAlarm();
 $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
 
 
document.getElementById("savebtn").addEventListener("click", saveAlarm , false);
```

```css
body { background:#A3ABF2; font-family:Arial; text-align:center; }
.day { font-size:64px;  }
.date { font-size:33px; }
.clock { font-size:44px; }
.clock-content { margin-top:35vh; color:#FFF;  }
.alarm-icon { font-size:34px; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:15px; right:15px; color:#FFF; }
.setalmlbl { padding-right:20px; }
.setalmtxtbox { margin-right:10px; width:60px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="alarmbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="fa fa-bell alarm-icon"></i>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Set Alarm</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
   <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
  
   <div class="form-inline">
     <label for="hours" class="setalmlbl" >Hours  </label>
     
    <select class="form-control setalmtxtbox" name="almHour" id="almHour">
    <script>
     for(var h = 1; h <= 12; h ++) {
      document.write("<option value="+ h +">" + h + "</option>");
      }
    </script>
    </select>
    
    <label for="minutes" class="setalmlbl"> Minutes  </label>
    <select class="form-control setalmtxtbox" name="almMin" id="almMin">
    <script>
     for(var m = 1; m <= 60; m++) {
      document.write("<option value="+ m +">" + m + "</option>");
      }
    </script>
    </select>
    <div class="form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="meridiem" id="am" value="am" checked>
     A.M.
     </label>
   </div> 
   <div class="form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="meridiem" id="pm" value="pm">
    P.M.
     </label>
   </div> 
    </form>
   
   
   
   </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  
  <div class="container-fluid">
   
   <div class="clock-content">
    <div class="day" id="day"></div>
    <div class="date" id="date"></div>
    <div class="clock" id="clock"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this simple javascript clock here in app.js for a live clock in the browser https://github.com/danielrussellLA/simpleClock

```
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');

setInterval(function(){
  clock.innerHTML = getCurrentTime();
}, 1);

function getCurrentTime() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var hours = currentDate.getHours() > 12 ? currentDate.getHours() - 12 : currentDate.getHours();
  hours === 0 ? hours = 12 : hours = hours;
  var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + currentDate.getSeconds() : currentDate.getSeconds();
  var currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  return currentTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

`new Date()` will give you the date for today. After getting the date get the hour, minutes, seconds from today's date.

`setTimeout(startTime, 1000)` will help you to run the timer continuously.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="startTime()">

<h2>JavaScript Clock</h2>

<div id="txt"></div>

<script>
function startTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple clock  would be somthing like

```
setInterval(() => {
     let arr  = Date().match(/\d{2}(?=:)|(?<=:)\d{2}/g).map(x => x = Number(x))
console.log(new Object({hours: arr[0], minutes: arr[1], seconds: arr[2]}))
},1000)
```

Its console logs out an array that is [h, m, s].

Answer (score 0):

```js
var span = document.getElementById('clock');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = 
    ("0" + h).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).substr(-2);
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

```js
var span = document.getElementById('span');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = 
    ("0" + h).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).substr(-2);
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "new time of day"? But in order to replace new time, you can create a div contain the time, and every time you call time(), set that div.innerHTML = "", like below

HTML:

```
<div id="curr_time"></div>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('curr_time'); 
function time() {
  div.innerHTML = "";
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  div.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```