# Make a live clock in 00:00 format

Tags: javascript, html

How can you make a live clock in **00:00** format? I've included my code down below. Is there a way to do this better or with shorter code?

> HTML

```
<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct'></span>
```

Now we just need to add the javascript part. This refreshes the clock every second so its "*Live*". Also it uses functions like `getMinutes` to fetch the current time.

> Javascript

```
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}
function display_ct() {
var x = new Date()
x1 = x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes();
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;
display_c();
 }
```

The 1000 milliseconds can be swapped out with more or less. 1000 is equal to 1 second so that would mean 500ms would be .5 seconds.

I'll include my code in an executable here:

```js
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}
function display_ct() {
var x = new Date()
x1 = x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes();
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;
display_c();
 }
```

```html
<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct'></span>
```

Comment: Just a hint, the minutes are only displayed as single digits, there is no 0, so it shows 15:3 and not 15:03

Comment: Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Please tag appropriately! There is no `php` involved in any of what you have shown.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll remove this tag right away! Edit: it's already been done. Thanks!

Comment: Please define "_better_" Do you want faster hours or ..?

Comment: No, as said in my code. *Is there a way to make it shorter?* There is a bug right now in this snippet where if the time is equal to lets say **15.05** it just shows it as **15.5**

Comment: @MarkdG maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a live clock in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418405/making-a-live-clock-in-javascript)

Comment: This works fine as well however what I have know works too.

Comment: You can left pad with 0: (new Date()).getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');

Comment: This was already suggested by: @firatozcevahir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.
Additionally you can use `padStart()` function to add leading zeros to your `string` values.

**Ps:** Because you are only showing hours and minutes, the clock will be updated every minute, instead of every seconds.(function still runs every second)

```js
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setInterval(display_ct, refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
  var x = new Date()
  x1 = x.getHours().toString().padStart(2,0) + ":" + x.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,0);
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;
  display_c();
}
```

```html
<body onload=display_ct();>
  <span id='ct'></span>
```

Comment: This worked. It properly shows the time now! I'll accept this answer in two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

make a js inside or out your main page like this

You must have an element with MyClockDisplay as id for this code

```js
    function showTime() {
        var date = new Date();
        var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
        var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
        var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
        var session = "AM";
        if (h == 0) {
            h = 12;
        }
        if (h > 12) {
            h = h - 12;
            session = "PM";
        }
        h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
        m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
        s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
        var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
        document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
        document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;
        setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    }
    showTime();
```

```html
<div id="MyClockDisplay"></div>
```